# Assigning default filtering values for complex API request model before passing it to business domain?

Tags: c#, api-design

I am writing an API (web-service) for my customers and there is an endpoint which allows to search for the documents in my storage (files, folders) by applyingg complex filters.

Initially, client need to send the following model to my API:

```
public class GetFactDocumentsTableWithFilterCommand : 
    IRequest<GetFactDocumentsTableCommandResult>, 
    ICommandWithIdentityAttached
{
    public string FolderId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FolderContentItemType> ContentType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> StatusId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> AuthorId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> ReceiverId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> DocumentTypeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FolderContentItemDirection> Direction { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FolderContentItemCategory> Category { get; set; }
    public DateTime ? CreatedOnFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime ? CreatedOnTo { get; set; }
    public int ? Top { get; set; }
    public int ? Page { get; set; }
    public string OrderBy { get; set; }
    public string OrderByDirection { get; set; }
    public IdentityUserInfo IdentityUserInfo { get; set; }
}
```

For example, suppose API caller wants to get all documents with statuses 1,2,5, that was created during the last month and intended to be sent to the external customer and that was formed by specific author. Than the caller need to create model and apply filtering values:

```
var filteringRequest = new GetFactDocumentsTableWithFilterCommand()
{
    StatusId = new List<int>() {1,2,5},
    CreatedOnFrom = new DateTime(2019, 05, 01),
    CreatedOnTo = new DateTime(2019, 05, 30),
    Direction = new List<FolderContentItemDirection>() { FolderContentItemDirection.External },
    AuthorId = new List<string>() { "author-id" }
};

var response = await _documentServerProxy.GetFactDocumentsTable(filteringRequest);
```

Caller do not need to fill all values, so if some values for filtering is missing, I need to assign default values. I created additional private method in my server-side, in service layer:

```
private async Task<GetFactDocumentsTableWithFilterCommand> PopulateWithDefaultFiletringOptionsForMissingMembers(
        GetFactDocumentsTableWithFilterCommand command)
    {
        // If no FolderId provided, it means that client requested the root folder.
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command.FolderId))
            command.FolderId = await GetRootFolderIdForCompany(command.IdentityUserInfo.CompanyId);

        // If can't parse FolderId, it means that client requested the wrong folder, cancel operation.
        bool canParseFolderIdToGuid = Guid.TryParse(command.FolderId, out var folderIdAsGuid);
        if (canParseFolderIdToGuid == false)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Provided FolderId is not a correct GUID sequence!", command.FolderId);

        if (command.ContentType == null) command.ContentType = Array.Empty<FolderContentItemType>();
        if (command.StatusId == null) command.StatusId = Array.Empty<int>();
        if (command.AuthorId == null) command.AuthorId = Array.Empty<string>();
        if (command.ReceiverId == null) command.ReceiverId = Array.Empty<string>();
        if (command.DocumentTypeId == null) command.DocumentTypeId = Array.Empty<int>();
        if (command.Direction == null) command.Direction = Array.Empty<FolderContentItemDirection>();
        if (command.Category == null) command.Category = Array.Empty<FolderContentItemCategory>();
        if (command.CreatedOnFrom == null) command.CreatedOnFrom = DateTime.MinValue;
        if (command.CreatedOnTo == null) command.CreatedOnTo = DateTime.MaxValue;

        int defaultTopValue = _configurationManager.GetTopValue(), defaultPageValue = 1;
        string defaultOrderBy = "DocumentName", defaultOrderByDirection = "descending";

        var allowedOrderByDirections = new string [] { "descending", "ascending" };

        if (command.Top.GetValueOrDefault() == 0) command.Top = defaultTopValue;
        if (command.Page.GetValueOrDefault() == 0) command.Page = defaultPageValue;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command.OrderBy)) command.OrderBy = defaultOrderBy;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command.OrderByDirection) ||
            allowedOrderByDirections.Contains(command.OrderByDirection) == false)
        {
            command.OrderByDirection = defaultOrderByDirection;
        }

        return command;
    }
```

In method `PopulateWithDefaultFiletringOptionsForMissingMembers` I have a lot of default values assigning logic, for example, Array.Empty and so on, because later this model will be used for generating LINQ-to-SQL query, so no NULL values allowed.

I wonder if it is correct approach for preparing my model for later processing or should I use another options, like assigning default values in model class itself, like:

```
public class GetFactDocumentsTableWithFilterCommand : 
IRequest<GetFactDocumentsTableCommandResult>, 
ICommandWithIdentityAttached
{
   public string FolderId { get; set; } = "default-folder-id";
   // so on...
}
```

I have doubts with such default-values in class declaration code, because some default values will be loaded from database, so I need somehow inject database-accessing code into my model class.

Basically, I want to know, how and where to assign default values for such DTOs, if some of default values stored in configuration files (like TOP), some of them stored in database (like FolderId).

Comment: my advice would be, dont create a new query language. either have simple GetXByY endpoints or use and off the shelf query syntax like elastic

Comment: If your model really needs that much translating to be passed to document server proxy, you might consider having separate models; a DTO class that your client submits to you and a domain model class that your code submits to the service. The translation would then take place in a portion of code responsible for mapping the two, e.g. using AutoMapper.